# Python/Django/MySQL "Incorrect string value" error

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode

I'm running a Django 1.4.2/Python 2.7.3/MySQL 5.5.28 site. One of the features of the site is that the admin can send an email to the server which calls a Python script via procmail that parses the email and tosses it into the DB. I maintain two versions of the site - a development and a production site. Both sites use different but identical vitualenvs (I even deleted them both and reinstalled all packages just to make sure).

I'm experiencing a weird issue. The *exact* same script succeeds on the dev server and fails on the production server. It fails with this error:

```
...django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:114: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\x92t kno...' for column 'message' at row 1
```

I'm well aware of the unicode issues Django has, and I know there are a ton of questions here on SO about this error, but I made sure to setup the database as UTF-8 from the beginning:

```
mysql> show variables like "character_set_database";
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like "collation_database";
+--------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name      | Value           |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| collation_database | utf8_general_ci |
+--------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Additionally, I know that each column can have its own charset, but the `message` column is indeed UTF-8:

```
mysql> show full columns in listserv_post;
+------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field      | Type         | Collation       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id         | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| thread_id  | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| timestamp  | datetime     | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| from_name  | varchar(100) | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| from_email | varchar(75)  | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| message    | longtext     | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error? Why is it happening under the production config but not the dev config?

Thanks!

[edit 1]
To be clear, the data are the same as well. I send a single email to the server, and procmail sends it off. This is what the .procmailrc looks like:

```
VERBOSE=off
:0
{
    :0c
    | <path>/dev/ein/scripts/process_new_mail.py dev > outputdev

    :0
    | <path>/prd/ein/scripts/process_new_mail.py prd > outputprd
}
```

There are 2 copies of process_new_mail.py, but that's just because it's version controlled so that I can maintain two separate environments. If I diff the two output files (which contain the message received), they're identical.

[edit 2]
I actually just discovered that both dev and prd configs are failing. The difference is that the dev config fails silently (maybe having to do with the `DEBUG` setting?). The problem is that there are some unicode characters in one of the messages, and Django is choking on them for some reason. I'm making progress....

I've tried editing the code to explicitly encode the message as ASCII and UTF-8, but it's still not working. I'm getting closer, though.

Comment: You say the **code** is identical, but what about the **data**? Maybe the bug exists in the dev environment as well, you only don't know about it. Try adding that row to the dev environment and see if the same error happens.

Comment: The data are exactly the same, too. I'm sending an email to the server, and I have procmail calling both the dev and production scripts simultaneously. I've even outputted the message just to make sure and diffed them, and they're identical.

Comment: My intuition may be wrong, but it just seems like it should be a DB issue. There are two different DBs, one for dev and one for prd, but I can't spot a difference between the two that would cause this problem.

Comment: Is there anything shared between those two instances? It makes no sense to have two identical codes behave differently, unless running the first one alters some state that the second one depends. I'd suggest swapping the order, executing the `prd` one first and the `dev` second, and see if the error still happens in the `prd`.

Comment: I've tried that. I've tried calling only the dev instance and only the prd instance as well as swapping the order, and no matter what I do, dev succeeds, and prd fails. That's what I'm thinking it may be some subtle UTF-8 DB structural issue. I only initialized the prd DB via Django's `syncdb` and [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) today, but the dev DB has been operational for several months now.

Comment: Also, to better determine whether the error is happening in the database or the python code, try swapping the DBs: have the `dev` environment access the `prd` database and vice-versa, and see which one fails.

Comment: Good call. I just tried that, and prd still failed, so that tells me it's probably something with the prd virtualenv, but I'm not really sure what.

Comment: Are you using the same [connection options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database) for both databases? Connection options like `charset` and `use_unicode` will make a difference.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to the my.cnf file (I'm not root on this server). The only Django options I use for the DB connection are the defaults (engine, name, user, password, host, and port). This shouldn't really be the issue, though, since both installs will use the same DB settings. I tried reinstalling MySQL-python, and that didn't fix it.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Django as well, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! The problem was that I wasn't parsing the email correctly with respect to the charsets. My fixed email parsing code comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166922/extracting-the-body-of-an-email-from-mbox-file-decoding-it-to-plain-text-regard) and [this post](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/11/19/parsing-multilingual-email-with-python/):

```
#get the charset of an email
#courtesy http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/11/19/parsing-multilingual-email-with-python/
def get_charset(message, default='ascii'):
    if message.get_content_charset():
        return message.get_content_charset()

    if message.get_charset():
        return message.get_charset()

    return default

#courtesy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166922/extracting-the-body-of-an-email-from-mbox-file-decoding-it-to-plain-text-regard
def get_body(message):
    body = None

    #Walk through the parts of the email to find the text body.
    if message.is_multipart():
        for part in message.walk():
            #If part is multipart, walk through the subparts.
            if part.is_multipart():
                for subpart in part.walk():
                    if subpart.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                        #Get the subpart payload (i.e., the message body).
                        charset = get_charset(subpart, get_charset(message))
                        body = unicode(subpart.get_payload(decode=True), charset)
            #Part isn't multipart so get the email body.
            elif part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                charset = get_charset(subpart, get_charset(message))
                body = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True), charset)
    #If this isn't a multi-part message then get the payload (i.e., the message body).
    elif message.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
        charset = get_charset(subpart, get_charset(message))
        body = unicode(message.get_payload(decode=True), charset)

    return body
```

Thanks very much for the help!