# Access thunderbird emails by python

Tags: python, email, thunderbird

I need to get informations out from my tree of Thunderbird message folders (which contains a large amount of email).

I need to be able to search the messages (optionally the attachments) and to report to the calling program.

There is some python module able to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I just discovered that Thunderbird format is fully mbox compatible, so that techniques as the one discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166922/extracting-the-body-of-an-email-from-mbox-file-decoding-it-to-plain-text-regard are ok - I approve the motion to close

Comment: see also https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyThunderbird

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you apparently figured out yourself already, yes.

The vanilla python module `mailbox`, which exists in any python 2 or 3 version, is all you need:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html